# Star rating: Update stars on click and don't lose the actual vote on re-hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a star based rating system.

First of all, I don't like to make it all with JS and only innerHTML the rated stars in a given `div`. I want to make it more like a plugin with the ability to make anything votable and you just have to pass the classes.

My biggest problem, however, is that I'm setting classes on hover and removing them on mouse leave. That's just fine until the user clicks and the classes are set. Think you can imagine what happens if the user hovers again: The classes would get removed.

But still I want the user to be able to change his vote. I managed it with two different divs where one is hidden. I absolutely don't feel comfortable with this solution:

```
<div class="votable hide">
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="2"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="3"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="4"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="5"></i>
</div>
<div class="voted">
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star" data-vote-type="1"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star" data-vote-type="2"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star" data-vote-type="3"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="4"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-3x fa-star-o" data-vote-type="5"></i>
</div>
```

With jQuery I'm enabling `.votable` on hover. On click I'm setting the actual vote to `.voted` and on mouse leave I'm hiding `.votable` and showing `.voted`.

```
$('.voted').hover(
    function() {
        $('.voted').addClass('hide');
        $('.votable').removeClass('hide');
    }
);

$('.votable').on('mouseleave',function(){
    $('.voted').removeClass('hide');
    $('.votable').addClass('hide');
});

$('.votable > i').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
        $(this).nextAll().removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    },
    function() {
        $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
    }
);

$('.votable > i').click(function(e) {
    var vote_type = $(this).attr('data-vote-type');
    var el = $('.voted > i[data-vote-type="' + vote_type + '"]');

    $(el).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('fa-star-o').addClass('fa-star');
    $(el).nextAll().removeClass('fa-star').addClass('fa-star-o');
});
```

You can see the code working at my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2s8x52e/1/).

What would be a better way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

About your HTML:

- Consider using the [`meter` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/forms.html#the-meter-element) to display the rating:

  ```
  <meter min="0" max="5" value="3">★★★☆☆</meter>
  ```

  (However, I don’t know how current user agents present this, i.e., if they add some special styling.)
- In any case, you [should *not* use the `i` element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669) for displaying an icon via CSS. Use `span` instead if you need an empty element.
- If you don’t want to use a `form` for voting, consider using [WAI-ARIA](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-wai-aria-20140320/) to make voting accessible.

Comment: You're right. I like to use <i> because it would perfectly fit for an icon. But it's of course intended to be used for italic. I don't know meter, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

As an item can have both the `voted` and `votable` classes, I'd make a specific style for items that have both.